# Check if DatetimeOffset is between 10 PM (today) and 2 AM (next day)

Tags: c#, datetime, timezone-offset, datetimeoffset, datetime-comparison

Below is the code that I have to check if currentDateInCST is between 10 PM and 2 AM (next day) in Central Standard Time. How do I make the startDate and endDate to be Central Standard Time ?

```
public DateTimeOffset GetTimeByTimeZone(DateTimeOffset? date, string windowsTimeZone)
{
        var timeZone = PlatformTimeZoneMapper.GetTimeZoneIdForPlatform(windowsTimeZone);
        var timeZoneInfo = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(timeZone);
        return effectiveDate.Value.ToOffset(timeZoneInfo.GetUtcOffset(date.Value));
}

var currentDateInCST = GetTimeByTimeZone(DateTimeOffset.Now, "Central Standard Time");
var startDate = new DateTimeOffset(currentDateInCST.Year, currentDateInCST.Month, currentDateInCST.Day, 22, 0, 0, new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0));
var tomorrowsDate = currentDateInCST.DateTime.AddDays(1);
var endDate = new DateTimeOffset(tomorrowsDate.Year, tomorrowsDate.Month, tomorrowsDate.Day, 2, 0, 0, new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0));

if (currentDateInCST >= startDate && currentDateInCST <= endDate)
{
}
```

Comment: Does the code you show not work? If so, how doesn't it work? The .NET date and time handling does a very poor job with time zones that are not _here_ or UTC. Consider looking at _NodaTime_

Comment: @Utasb - It's unclear what you are asking for.  How would the current date (today) _ever_ be in tomorrow's date - unless you are comparing wall times between two different time zones? (You've only mentioned one here.)

Comment: @Flydog57 - NodaTime's APIs are more pedantic in a way that encourages correct usage, while .NET's built-in APIs are more simplistic in a way that can also allow the developer to make mistakes.  But I wouldn't characterize it as doing a poor job with non-local, non-UTC time zones.  There is plenty of support for that, which will lead to correct results when used as designed.

Answer (score 0):

In your code if the `currentDateInCST` is at 1am, it will look for 2AM of the next day (which is over 24 hours away). I doubt this is what you want. However if it is, I would say in this case it is easier to compare DateTimes, which is independent to TimeZones when `kind` is not set to UTC.

You can get the current CST Datetime by using `TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime`.

```
var currentDateInCST = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(DateTime.Now,
        TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Central Standard Time"));
var nextDay = currentDateInCST.Date.AddDays(1);
var startDate = nextDay.AddHours(-2);
var endDate = nextDay.AddHours(2);

if (currentDateInCST > startDate && currentDateInCST < endDate)
{
    //do stuff
}
```

If what you actually want is to see if the currentCST time is between 10pm and 2am within the timezone offset, simply compare the `Hour` of the currentDateInCST.

```
var currentDateInCST = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(DateTime.Now,
        TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Central Standard Time"));

if(currentDateInCST.Hour > 22 && currentDateInCST.Hour < 2)
{
    //do stuff
}
```

Finally, to answer how to set the DateTimeOffset to CST and use it to compare:

```
var nextDay = currentDateInCST.Date.AddDays(1);
DateTimeOffset startDate = new DateTimeOffset(nextDay.AddHours(-2),
                  TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Central Standard Time").GetUtcOffset(nextDay.AddHours(-2)));
DateTimeOffset endDate = new DateTimeOffset(nextDay.AddHours(2),
                  TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Central Standard Time").GetUtcOffset(nextDay.AddHours(2)));
if (currentDateInCST > startDate && currentDateInCST < endDate)
{
    //do stuff
}
```